# Segfault while using Malloc

Tags: malloc

I'm having a segmentation fault while using malloc, I'm not sure what's causing it (new to C) betting it's something stupid I'm missing.

The segfault occurs on the line preceding "printf("test\n");

EDIT: Either I am confused... or it decided to change when it printed the segfault since after I followed one of the suggested changes...it decided to work (that change was after the printf("test")   thanks for your help guys

As far as I can tell, it should work to multiply sizeof(int) by the value numitem points to

But the segfault would mean it can't access the data stored somewhere in there...

EDIT: Added the rest of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * readIntFile(char[], int*);

int main(){



char fileName[255];
int *grades;
int *numItems = malloc(sizeof(int));

printf("Please input the file name you would like to open:");
scanf("%s", fileName);
printf("the input string is \"%s\"\n ", fileName);
grades = readIntFile(fileName, (int*) numItems);
printf("%d\n\n", *grades); //I know this line only prints the first index, it's
                               //for testing

}

int * readIntFile( char fileName[], int *numItem ){
FILE *fp;

int holder;
*numItem = 0;

fp = fopen(fileName, "r");//open file to to read

while( fscanf(fp, "%d", &holder) == 1 && !feof(fp))
         (*numItem)++;

rewind(fp);

int *oneGrade = malloc(sizeof(int) * (*numItem));
printf("test\n");
for(; fscanf(fp, "%d", *oneGrade) == 1 &&  !feof(fp); oneGrade++); 

return oneGrade;    




}
```

Thanks for any help

EDIT:   I am using a pointer for numItem because...as specified by the assignment I have to be able to access that value back in main (in the specified way)...I can't just stick it at the end of oneGrade and return it that way  :|

Comment: Can I ask if there's a specific reason why you're using an int pointer, rather than just ``int numItem``?

Comment: numItem isn't null, it has memory allocated (in main) and contains 0. By the end of the first while loop (based of my sample data)   *numItem = 12

Comment: Perhaps you could show the line from `main` that calls it. Also if you put a `printf("%d\n", *numItem);` after `rewind(fp);` do you get a print out of what is in `*numItem`?

Comment: Yeah, I tested everything up to that point....with my sample data *numItem is equal to 12  (also, stupid question...how do you place the code snippets in blocks like that in the comments)

Comment: @user2489837 just use back-ticks for the little snippet quotes. Also used for inline snippets in questions and answers.

Comment: yay  success on testing that   thanks again   `yay`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", *oneGrade)
```

`oneGrade` is a `int *`. So `*oneGrade` is a random value at this point, let alone not intended to be an address. You probably wanted `fscanf(fp, "%d", oneGrade)`. `fscanf` needs the pointer to the location you want to read the value into.

You also do need a check to make sure `*numItem` is greater than zero before the `malloc` for `oneGrade`.

Comment: wow, I was right it was a stupid mistake...thank you.  (I needed to input the memory address..not the data that oneGrade was pointing to)  Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

One useful advice, always check the pointer before dereferencing it:

```
if(oneGrade !=NULL)
```

Now, to your error:

If `numItem` remains 0 after:

```
while( fscanf(fp, "%d", &holder) == 1 && !feof(fp))
         (*numItem)++;
```

This would mean, you `malloc` `0 bytes`, and `malloc` won't return any valid address,

```
int *oneGrade = malloc(sizeof(int) * (*numItem));
```

`oneGrade` will not point to any valid address, and when you derefence it,

```
for(; fscanf(fp, "%d", *oneGrade) == 1 &&  !feof(fp); oneGrade++);
```

you get segfault.